# Split using a bracket

Tags: java, regex, split

How can I split a string using `[` as the delimiter?

```
String line = "blah, blah [ tweet, tweet";
```

if I do

```
line.split("[");
```

I get an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Unclosed character class near index 1 [

Any help?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `[` is a reserved char in regex, you need to escape it,

```
line.split("\\[");
```

Answer (score 6):

Just escape it :

```
line.split("\\[");
```

`[` is a special metacharacter in regex which needs to be escaped if not inside a character class such as in your case.

Answer (score 6):

The `split` method operates using regular expressions. The character `[` has special meaning in those; it is used to denote character classes between `[` and `]`. If you want to use a literal opening square bracket, use `\\[` to escape it as a special character. There's two slashes because a backslash is also used as an escape character in Java String literals. It can get a little confusing typing regular expressions in Java code.

Answer (score 4):

The `[` character is interpreted as a special regex character, so you have to escape it:

`line.split("\\[");`

Answer (score 3):

Please use `"\\["` instead of `"["`.

Answer (score 0):

if have to split between [] then try `str.split("[\\[\\]]");`