# Java Regexp: Split by both brackets

Tags: java

I'm aware that to split by brackets I need to use the `\\[` notation, per this thread: [Split using a bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141698/split-using-a-bracket)

However, I need to get tokens from both [ and ].

An example string is `study[2]` from whcih I need to get the token `2`.

The following gives an Error in Eclipse's Expression Debugger:

```
"study[2]".split("\\[\\]");
```

Is there another regexp I should use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex). It looks like you're really trying to just get the substring between the two brackets. That question is similarly asking about how to get the substring between two single quotes.

Comment: You say you want to *split*, but it sounds more like you want to extract a substring defined by the pattern.  If so, then `String.split()` is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to *split*, you have to do a group of the brackets.

```
"study[2]".split("[\\[\\]]");
```

Because that String is difficult to read, here again the regex without Java-escaping

```
[\[\]]
```

This means, you have a group (the outer brackets) containing two elements, `[` and `]`, each of which is escaped. This means, split at either `[` or `]`. According to this, a String like `"a]bc[1]2[][3"` will be split at every bracket, so you get `a`, `bc`, `1`, `2`, `3`.

If your problem is simpler than I assume here, the answer of @user1766169 is less of an overkill.

Comment: Well basically my question calls for a StringTokenizer, where I can do "[]" without a regexp. But I hate doing nextToken() twice.

Comment: thanks for the response I guess that was it. was missing that extra ]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to split using either of [ or ], then use

```
"study[2]".split("[\\[\\]]");
```

**Output:-**

```
study
2
```

If your intention is to extract the number within the brackets, use below:-

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\[([0-9]+)\\].*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("study[2]");
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

**OutPut:-**

```
true
2
```

> Note:- the m.matches() needs to be called, otherwise m.group(1) will
>   not return any result.

**Regex String in Detail**

```
.*  - match any character 0 or more times 

\\[  - an escaped [ character

(  - open the braces to group items. These matched groups can be later re-used.

[0-9]+  - match any number.

)  - grouping ends. Anything inside a group is accessible by calling group(1) (1 for the first group). 

\\]  - an escaped ] character

.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Use substring instead:

```
String testString = "study[2]";
int startIndex = testString.indexOf("[");
int endIndex = testString.indexOf("]");
String subString = testString.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex);
System.out.println(subString);
```

This will print 2.

Comment: This will cause an issue for a string like `Apple ][` where brackets are in different orders, and will also only find the first match if there are multiples as in `foo[1]bar[2]`. But if all input strings are guaranteed to be formatted like `foo[1]`, then this really is the best solution since regexes would be overkill.