# How to split string with a specific word contains special characters in it

Tags: java, split

For Example :
I have a string coming from some Api call like below :
And I want to split based on [DART1].

```
String value = "University[DART1]BUCKKKKK";
String[] splitData = value.split("DART1");
String firstWord = splitData[0].substring(0, splitData[0].length() - 1);
String secondWord = splitData[1].substring(1);
```

I did a split and removed those special characters from the string, but I was doing lot of operation on string.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try `"\\[DART1\\]"`

Comment: @Thefourthbird cool! That did work. Thank you:)

Comment: just `"\\[DART1]"` should suffice the second `\\\` is redundant. @Thefourthbird

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141698/split-using-a-bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split based on `"\\[DART1]"`

```
String[] result = value.split("\\[DART1]");
```

1. The `\\` is required to escape the `[` otherwise the compiler would think you want to split on anything that's either `D`, `A`, `R`, `T` or `1`.

Then you can access the individual elements by indexing into the `result` array.